# Specify prerequisites for only some files in a list

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If `main.cpp` includes `functions.h`, does `main.o` have to be re-linked if `functions.h` changes?

If not, I'm wondering when I have a list of files like this:

```
objects = main.o factorial.o hello.o
```

and `factorial.cpp` (which defines a function declared in functions.h), and `hello.cpp` (which defines a function declared in functions.h), and `main.cpp` all include `functions.h`; and I have a rule like this:

```
$(objects): %.o: %.cpp
    recipe
```

how do I specify that only some of the files in `$(objects)` should have a prerequisite of `functions.h`?  If I create a special rule only for `main.o`:

```
main.o: main.cpp 
    recipe

$(objects): %.o: %.cpp functions.h
  recipe
```

does the second rule also get applied to main.o, thereby unnecessarily having the prerequisite functions.h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `main.cpp` includes the header file `functions.h`, then `main.o` should be rebuilt whenever `functions.h` changes.

You can specify some files should depend on headers by simply writing the prerequisites you want:

```
objects = main.o factorial.o hello.o

$(objects): %.o: %.cpp
        recipe

factorial.o hello.o: functions.h
```

Now those two `.o` files depend on `functions.h` but `main.o` doesn't.

*EDIT*

Ha, a classic case of getting the answer to the question you asked, not the question you wanted answered :).

You can easily do this with the [filter](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-filter) and [filter-out](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-filter_002dout) functions.  For example suppose you have:

```
SOME := foo.o bar.o
ALL := $(SOME) biz.o baz.o boz.o blah.o blee.o bor.o bag.o

$(ALL): %.o: %.cpp
        recipe

$(filter-out $(SOME),$(ALL)): functions.h
```

However, maybe you should step further back and ask yourself if you really want or need to do this.  If you are really talking about header files in C/C++ programs here, not something else, and you really have that many files, maybe you should consider adding [automatic dependency generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) to your makefiles instead of writing it all out by hand.

Comment: Hi Mad, thanks for the response. Okay, your first answer means I had the wrong belief in my head to begin with. I considered your second answer, but if the objects list had 1,000 names in it, it wouldn't be practical to write out all the names in your last rule, so that was the problem I was having. I was hoping there was some way to write `$(objects) - main.o`. I also added a bit to the end of my question. How does that work?

Comment: No, just reading some tutorials and wondering about how things work.  Thanks for the help.